# POD class with inline construction inside of an expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I want to write a 2d (mathematical) vector class that holds an X and Y value. I want it to have overloads for operators such as + so I can easily use it to express mathematical formulas in my code. Consider this:

```
template <class T>
struct Vector
{
    T x, y;

    inline Vector<T> operator +(const Vector& other) const
    {
        return {x + other.x, y + other.y};
    }
};
```

As you can see I made use of C++11's ability to use initializer lists in return statements. However, they're still not expressions - I can't apply operations to them. And here comes my problem. I want the class to be POD. I can't define custom constructors so that I can initialize x and y via parameters. This is fine because I can use initializer lists for construction, e.g.:

```
Vector<int> foo = {1, 2};
```

However, I cannot use that when I need to construct another Vector inside of an expression (operator * isn't defined but that doesn't matter here):

```
Vector<int> result = (foo + {1, 2}) * 12;
```

As I stated before the constructor alternative is not an option. I would love to hear any input on this, because I can't think of any solutions to this problem, other than storing {1, 2} in a named variable.

Comment: *"I want the class to be trivial"* - Could you add why? Maybe *trivially copyable* might be sufficient for you (which isn't violated by a custom non-copy/move constructor)? Because then you can just write the straight-forward two-argument constructor and profit from uniform initialization in contrast to initializer lists (you know the difference, do you?).

Comment: Yes, I do know the difference between trivial and trivially copyable. I'm new to C++11 - I actually wanted it to be POD, in fact (for low footprint), sorry for the confusion. But: I was unaware of the uniform initialization syntax - I googled it and figured that I could write Vector<int>{1, 2} in my example and that would work fine. This basically completely answered my question, thanks :) However, the second part of your answer confuses me. You said that I could write a straight-forward constructor, but why would I even have do that if I can just use the solution that I mentioned before?

Comment: Well, `Vector<int>{1,2}` isn't much of a win over `Vector<int>(1,2)` (and I don't know why you are so happy with that). But I think with uniform initialization you should be able to write `{1,2}` in vector expressions (just like your second code snippet), once `Vector` has a constructor taking two ints (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: And usually *POD* isn't that much important. What is much more important are the parts its made of, which are *standard-layout* (which you always have with your simple vector, disreagrding any constructors), *trivially default-constructible* (which makes plain `malloc` work) and *trivially copyable* (which makes plain `memcpy` and binary serialization work). And maybe trivially copyable would be enough for you and you don't need plain `malloc` (without construction) to work for your vectors.

Comment: POD doesn't have anything to do with any memory footprint. While not guaranteed, no compiler will pad your vector with any rubbish apart from two plain `int`s, no matter what constructors or members it has. Just don't put any virtual functions or weird base classes in there. On the other hand if it was POD there still wouldn't be any strict guarantee for no padding. POD is about C-compatiblity and understandable representation, not about memory footprint.

Comment: I didn't specifically mean memory footprint, sorry for being vague there. I was basically talking about CPU footprint, i.e. I don't want there to be any unnecessary code running to construct/destruct my Vector etc. - I just want it to be a plain old pair of two integral types with some syntactical sugar. I'm probably not writing anything that absolutely requires this to run at a reasonable speed, but I love the sugar and will instantiate this class very often - I'd feel bad about the unnecessary construction code running (I might be totally underestimating optimizers in this regard).

Comment: Ok, if that is your reason, then striving for POD is even more unneccessary. If you write a trivial default-constructor youself (that doesn't zero- or value initialize the `int`s) then there is no need for any overhead. Calling an empty no-op function doesn't really call a function, it, well, does nothing. You're not totally underestimating optimizers, you're completely ignoring them. Even the most trivial compiler knows, that a function that *does absolutely nothing* doesn't have to be called.

Comment: I'd like to believe you, but I've just written a simple benchmark program that clearly shows a speed gain for the POD implementation: http://bpaste.net/show/CVJc8zqkvoWRraW32da5/ compiled with clang, default options (and of course -std=c++11), I get 94ms vs 265ms. I *know* that that code is quite unoptimized and in this particular case you could rewrite some of it easily etc. etc., but that's besides the point. I'm just talking about the overall speed difference here.

Comment: Ok inded, that is probably due to the fact that the compiler can fold the second (POD initalizer list) version into a mere constant value. Making the `Slow` constructor `constexpr` might fix that (though in this is just a suggestion to the compiler, but well, what else is POD). But I cannot check it right now, being tied to VS for the moment.

Comment: Hmm, I added constexpr but It didn't make any difference. Anyway, thank you for all your input - I will try to find more information about this online. I will go with the POD solution for now, because I don't think it will do any harm.

Comment: Well, [*gcc 4.5* thinks you may have compiled without optimization](http://ideone.com/TdiUsH), anyway. But in the end that test isn't much of value anyway, since you always use the same computation on the same inputs in each iteration.

Comment: By the way, your code incorrectly uses an `int` constructor even for the `double` version of slow (which is probably a typo and should be `T`). And of course converting between double and int is always a bad idea performance-wise.

Comment: Yeah, I actually noticed the int typo and fixed it immediately. Apparently I was too late! Adding -O gives me ~15ms with both (GetTickCount is very innacurate, so let's say they're equal). I guess you were right, optimizations work wonders there :)

Comment: In the end nobody cares about runtime without optimizations.

Comment: That's right - I just didn't know that optimizations are completely turned off by default in clang (I'm using it for the first time, for C++ 11 - I guess I better RTFM, so I'm sorry for that.)

Comment: I tried to look it up and wasn't sure, too, but if it mimicks *gcc* in this regard, then the default is indeed `-O0` (no optimization).

Comment: Ah. Anyway thanks for this, I guess I really have to stop underestimating modern C++ compilers. Lesson learned.

Comment: In the end I am myself usually rather skeptical of the compiler's abilities and prefer to make it as easy for the compiler as possible. But there are things that can really be assumed as given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the easiest option is to just create a temporary using aggregate initialisation:

```
Vector<int> result = (foo + Vector<int>{1, 2}) * 12;
```

Alternatively, you could do some magic with C++11's user-defined literals so that something like `"1,2"_v` becomes one of your objects:

```
Vector<int> operator "" _v(const char* literal, size_t)
{
  std::stringstream literal_stream(literal);
  Vector<int> vec;
  literal_stream >> vec.x;
  literal_stream.ignore();
  literal_stream >> vec.y;
  return vec;
}
```

You could definitely do with some format checking in here though. Then you can do:

```
Vector<int> result = (foo + "1,2"_v) * 12;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you - the first solution is exactly what I stumbled across thanks to Christian Rau in his comment. The second one is interesting, and it shows the power of user defined literals, but the first one will do just fine!

Comment: @looki While this may be a sufficient solution to you for now, you might end up with an even better solution for your whole vector class problem if you start clearing up your knowledge about POD, standard-layout and trivial and what those mean in theory and practice (since I have a strong doubt your vector really needs to be trivially default-constructible).

Comment: Your concern might be justified. It doesn't *have* to be as I stated in my other answer, but as far as I know it being POD will only make it faster in extreme cases, not slower.

Comment: @looki It won't practically ever make it any faster (of course nobody is concerned about debug builds, but even there I'm not sure). But it makes your vector harder to use (and not only in extreme cases).